# Server rendering react-router v4 passthrough if 404

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, react-router, isomorphic-javascript

In react-router v3 we could know when server side rendering had not matched against the current url. This allowed me to pass the request to my `express.static` middleware instead of sending the rendered App.

In react-router v4, we must use

```
    const htmlData = renderToString(
        <StaticRouter
            location={req.url}
            context={context}
        >
            <App/>
        </StaticRouter>
    );
```

in order to render on the server side. However, it automatically redirects everything to `/`. Why does this behavior even exist? Couldn't we just have an error like we expect insted of it silently failing?

How could I know that nothing matched so that I can call `next()` and have the other express's routes do the job?

Here is the whole function which I'd like to use:

```
app.get('*', (req, res, next) => {
    const context = {};
    const htmlData = renderToString(
        <StaticRouter
            location={req.url}
            context={context}
        >
            <App/>
        </StaticRouter>
    );

    console.log(JSON.stringify(context, null, 4)); // empty object
    if (context.url) { // <------------------------ Doesn't work (taken from example and thought it would contain the unmatched url)
        winston.info(`Passing ${req.url} along`);
        next(); // <--------------- Never called even if no route matches.
    } else {
        res.send(pageContent.replace('<div id="main"></div>',
            `<div id="main">${htmlData}</div>`));
    }
});
```

I tried doing stuff based on [this](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/guides/server-rendering.md#404-401-or-any-other-status) but the `// somewhere else` is so precise, I couldn't understand it at all.

Here is my last attempt in case it is of any help. This is the `Router.jsx` file where I plan to define all my `Route`s.

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {
    BrowserRouter,
    Route,
} from 'react-router-dom';
import App from './components/App.jsx';

export const Status = ({ code, children }) => (
    <Route render={({ staticContext }) => {
        if (staticContext) {
            staticContext.status = code;
        }
        return children;
    }}/>
);

Status.propTypes = {
    code     : PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    children : PropTypes.node.isRequired,
};

export const NotFound = () => (
    <Status code={404}>
        <div>
            <h1>Sorry, can’t find that.</h1>
        </div>
    </Status>
);

class Router extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <BrowserRouter>
                <div>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={App}/>
                    <Route component={NotFound}/>
                </div>
            </BrowserRouter>
        );
    }
}

export default Router;
```

(I know this doesn't make any sense at all since `StaticRouter` directly uses `App` without caring about `Router.jsx` but I have no `Route` at all inside `App` so I don't really understand how to do things, I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put NotFoundPage component route logic inside your App.jsx file, not Route.jsx which you are not using at all.

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={AppRootComponent}/>
    <Route component={NotFound}/>
</Switch>
```

In addition to this, this [tutorial code](https://github.com/lmammino/judo-heroes-2) is a great reference for server-side rendering using react router v4.

Comment: Alright so my Routing should be defined inside App instead of Router? And Router shoud just do `<BrowserRouter><App/></BrowserRouter>`?